# How to get UITextField values when it s dynamically created

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitextfield

I am creating textField dynamically by the following code:

```
for (int i=0; i<count_size; i++) {
    //UITextfield in UIview
    CGRect myTextField = CGRectMake(8, 5, 60, 30);
    UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myTextField];
    [txtField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [txtField setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [txtField setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
    [txtField setDelegate:self];
    txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
    [txtField setPlaceholder:@"0"];
    txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    [myFirstView addSubview:txtField];
}
```

Now i want to get value entered in textfields.

I came to know about delegate protocol for UITextField.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    NSLog(@"Dic: %@",textField.text);

}
```

But I am not able to implement how to store this values at index they were created, like i want first textField to be stored at index 0 of array and so on. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tag` property which every UIView subclass has:

```
for (int i=0; i<count_size; i++) {
      //UITextfield in UIview
    CGRect myTextField = CGRectMake(8, 5, 60, 30);
    UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myTextField];
    txtField.tag = i;
    ...
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
      int index = textField.tag;
      // Now save text using that index
      NSLog(@"Dic: %@",textField.text);
}
```

P.S. Since 0 is default value for a tag property it may be better to adjust tags to make them start from arbitrary non-zero value.